# logging.fileConfig() acting weird on Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

I have a simple webapp2 app on Google app engine. Here is the code

```
# log.py.........................................................................
logging_defaults = {
    'loglevel': 'DEBUG',
}
logging_config = """\
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=stderr

[formatters]
keys=default

[logger_root]
level=%(loglevel)s
handlers=stderr

[handler_stderr]
class=StreamHandler
level=NOTSET
formatter=default
args=(sys.stderr, )

[formatter_default]
format=%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s:%(lineno)d %(message)s
datefmt=
"""

import logging
import logging.config
import logging.handlers
from cStringIO import StringIO
config_file = StringIO(logging_config)
logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, logging_defaults)
l = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# helloworld.py......................................................

import webapp2
from log import l

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      l.debug('debug message')
      l.info('info message')
      l.warn('warn message')
      l.error('error message')
      l.critical('critical message')
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
      self.response.write("hello me!! It's me here ;)")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

And here is the screen-shot of the logs produced in app engine dashboard

[image: log-screenshot]

As you can see the logs show up fine, but every log is marked with 'E' which represents error even if it's not an error. And as far as I can tell this happens everytime I use

```
logging.config.fileConfig()
```

Is there a fix to this problem ?

PS: I know there are other methods to configure logging. But I am asking for fileConfig() only.

UPDATE: I tried using loading from a real file with fileConfig() and using dictConfig() but each time the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the cause of your problem is this:

```
[formatter_default]
format=%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s:%(lineno)d %(message)s
```

This differs from App Engine's default log format, which puts the level first, followed by the datetime. As a result, the App Engine admin console can't parse your log messages to determine what level each log entry is at, so it defaults to an error. Reverse the `%(asctime)s` and `%(levelname)s` arguments and it should work fine.

Comment: it still doesn't seem to work. I even tried setting `format=%(levelname)s` still no success.
have a look http://i.imgur.com/sjOgm.png

Comment: I suspect it's still a formatting issue. You need to check what App Engine apps are outputting by default and imitate that - or better, just don't modify the log format in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue recently, 
use `google.appengine.api.app_logging.AppLogsHandler` instead of `StreamHandler` solve this issue for me.